# Getting different height click position by scrolling main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a spot the difference game with jQuery.
Basically, several images stacked, positioned absolutely in a container. Above the container there is the page header with a logo and a menu, which takes altogather about 120px above the images container.

When someone clicks an area inside the image, I put there a new div, with either a correct (V) mark, or a wrong (red X).

I'm trying to get the position of the click inside the element, using the following code (the following used event variable e is returned in the click event just to be clear):

```
var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();  
var topOffset = e.clientY - offset.top;
```

My problem is that the offset from the top changes when I scroll the page down a little to the footer area, and then I do not position the new marker div in the correct height.

When I'm scrolled to the top of the page, the mark is position correctly.

I've created such a game before, but can't understand why suddenly the calculation is wrong :\
Seems that I get the distance minus the scroll height, but not sure.

Thanks for your insight,
Yanipan

Comment: try finding scrolling offset with: `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: Thanks Davor, used your tip to get the delta of the heights :)

Comment: post your solution, so other that have same problem could found it.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with Firebug a little and it looks like `e.originalEvent.layerY` is exactly what you're looking for.

It always shows the absolute coordinates of your click within the clicked object, no matter where the screen is scrolled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Deathmic, but I actually used Davors hint and just calculated the delta of the heights. Thanks for reminding me that sometimes debugging the event is the simple way to go.